# Handling Overfitting(diverging val loss and train loss) in Conv-LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, convolutional-neural-network, overfitting, binary-classification

This is related to an Educational Research Project I'm using to learn stuff so please be kind.

I'm working on a video binary classification task. I have almost 1400
videos of both classes.

- I also augmented(horizontal flip) them to double the amount of
  training data to overcome the overfitting issue.
- I have tried increasing the dropout values starting from 0.2 up to
  0.5 in every layer, including the recurrent_dropout.
- I've changed the units in each layer as well as the number of layers
  to decrease the complexity of my model. Went all the way from 600,000 parameters to 50,000 parameters.

But all this just causes the divergence of losses to become slower(smaller slope). I'm out of ideas, you can find the graphs of results over [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qc_49zjecDFUZPPVajGNNaUVDzXUpxuO?usp=sharing). I'm also posting most of the relevant code regarding my network, which includes all the changes I made, below. Please let me know what I'm missing here, probably is something really dumb. Thanks!

```
frame_features_input = tf.keras.Input((MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMG_CHANNELS))
mask_input = tf.keras.Input((MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="bool")
  
#Layers - 1
x = ConvLSTM2D(4, (3, 3), activation = 'tanh', data_format = 'channels_last', recurrent_dropout = 0.5, return_sequences = True)(inputs = frame_features_input, mask = mask_input)
x = MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (1, 2, 2), padding = 'same', data_format = 'channels_last')(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(x)
#Layers - 2
x = ConvLSTM2D(8, (3, 3), activation = 'tanh', data_format = 'channels_last', recurrent_dropout = 0.5, return_sequences = True)(x)
x = MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (1, 2, 2), padding = 'same', data_format = 'channels_last')(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(x)
#Layers - 3
x = ConvLSTM2D(8, (3, 3), activation = 'tanh', data_format = 'channels_last', recurrent_dropout = 0.5, return_sequences = True)(x)
x = MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (1, 2, 2), padding = 'same', data_format = 'channels_last')(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(x)
#Flatten
x = Flatten()(x)
#Dense
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
convlstm_model = tf.keras.Model([frame_features_input, mask_input], output)
# convlstm_model.load_weights("best_weights_AD_best_val_acc")
convlstm_model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I suggest trying something more plain then ConvLSTM2D and see how loss behaves.

Comment: Have you normalized the inputs? Usually when it comes to loss solution is either activation function or normalization